# Php Soap Client suddenly fails: Couldn't find <definitions>

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Very peculiar problem follows.

I call a service through PHP using a SoapClient:

`$url = "https://paycenter.piraeusbank.gr/services/tickets/issuer.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient($url);`

This has been working for years, until yesterday noon. Since then and without any change, I'm getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find <definitions> in 'https://paycenter.piraeusbank.gr/services/tickets/issuer.asmx?WSDL'`

The PHP version is 5.6

The WSDL document seems well formatted. However, when I try to connect to another service (e.g. https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/airavata/sandbox/xbaya-web/test/Calculator.wsdl;), there's no problem.

Also when I upload the simple script above to another server (running PHP 5.3) there's no error.

What is going on?

Comment: Have you tried emptying WSDL cache?

Comment: Yes, good guess but I've tried both ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0); and $client = new SoapClient($url, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE) ); with no luck

Comment: Hmm, which exact minor version of PHP 5.6 do you have? Is it thread-safe or non-thread safe?

Comment: it is 5.6.22 and thread safety is disabled